# Using Sum function with Vlookup

Tags: excel-2013

Structure:

```
Sheet1: Account ID, Total
Sheet2: Account ID, Amt - Multiple amounts for each account ID
```

Want sum in Sheet 1 `Account ID` ---> `Total` for `Amt` in Sheet 2

Comment: Did you get this working?

Answer (score 0):

So what you need a couple of named ranges. select your `Amt` from `Sheet2` and Define its name (Amt works) and Select your `Account ID` also from `Sheet2` and Define their name (Account works), then in the `Total` column on `Sheet1` use this formula:

```
=SUMIFS(Amt,Account,A2)
```

And copy this down. This is assuming that your Account ID's start in A2